# is there a system event I can hook into for time updates with .NET?

Tags: c#, time, timer, system

I'm building an application that needs to fire an event every second, but it needs to be at the top of every second. Firing between seconds is not good enough. I don't think a timer will be acceptable since, while I can set it to fire every second, I can not tell it to start at the top of the second. And it will probably drift slightly over time.

Is there maybe a system level event that i can hook into that will fire as the system time updates?

Any other ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: So long as your timer fires exactly once a second, isn't 'the top of every second' a relative measurement?  That is, if your computer is 250ms ahead of mine, then what does it matter if it's the 'top' of the second?

Comment: Is it really true that only two of your 11 questions in the last several months have received an acceptable answer? Two?

Comment: how much jitter is acceptable to you?

Comment: Marcus I think you're right. Brain fart.

TJ Crowder, I don't really participate in all the voting on this site, I just ask questions.

Comment: stmax, +- 10ms would be acceptable. Windows timers seem to drift beyond this after a while.

Comment: @user113164: I think you should participate after all this site is about giving and receiving in spirit of SO, not to be sounding harsh or cruel, but that's a selfish attitude - ask questions and not bother upvoting others...that's what makes this SO a community thing...

Comment: How much time you think the system needs to raise an event that its time has been changed? and do you think the system should raise an event every second? millisecond? or even less? I think Marcus comment is correct, +1 from me Marcus.

Comment: @user113164, i dont mind sharing knowledge, but as long as it is sharing. We don't get paid to answer your questions.

Comment: @user113164 - you "pay" for your answers by upvoting.

Comment: @user113164 - how close to the top of the second do you need in milliseconds?

Comment: If your "acceptance" is higher, you may get more answers.

Comment: "So long as your timer fires exactly once a second, isn't 'the top of every second' a relative measurement?", no. If you change your statement to "...the top of each period..." then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this before with great success on a moble device. This method also eliminates drift (jitter).

1. Set your timer to a small interval.
2. Save time.
3. On tick event,
4. Compare current time to saved time.
5. If time different (seconds changed),

   5. then do something
   6. and save time

In my specific case, my timer interval was 100ms, so I could catch second changes within 100ms. You will set your interval to 10ms.

<strike>Depending on your needs,</strike> you <strike>may</strike> will want to consider using a server-based timer.

[update] It is faster to store the time as Integer (tick count) and not a DateTime. On initialization, you loop until the second changes, then store the tick count (Environment.TickCounts). When current tick count minus saved tick count is greater than 1000, you know a second has passed.